# Lo4j2 config setup

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm trying to setup log4j2 config xml. I had made below setup for logging specific package under different log files.

Log4j2.xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<configuration status="error">  
  
    <Appenders>  

        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">  

            <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>  

            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}][%t][%-5level][%class{36}][%L][%M]: %msg%xEx%n"/>  
        </Console>  
  

        <RollingFile name="Applog" fileName="/logs/AppService.log" filePattern="/usr/local/tomcat/logs/AppService.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">  
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class{36} %L %M ]: %msg%xEx%n"/>  
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />                              
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>  

    </Appenders> 

    <loggers>             

        <logger name="com.java.app.restservices.migration"  additivity="false">         
            <AppenderRef ref="Applog"/>
        </logger>

       <logger name="org.apache"  level="warn" additivity="false">          
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </logger>

       <logger name="org.exolab"  level="warn" additivity="false">          
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="com.java.app"  additivity="false">        
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </logger>

     
        <root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>              
        </root>

    </loggers>  
</configuration>
```

Java class example:

```
package com.java.app;

import org.apache.log4j.Category;

public class HelloWorld {

     private static Category category = Category.getInstance(HelloWorld.class.getName());

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            category.debug("Hello from Log4j 2");
            category.info("Hello from Log4j 2");
            category.error("Hello from Log4j 2");
        }

}
```

Restservices package:

```
package com.java.app.restservices.migration;

import org.apache.log4j.Category;

public class HelloRestService {

     private static Category category = Category.getInstance(HelloRestService .class.getName());

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            category.debug("Hello Rest Services from Log4j 2");
            category.info("Hello Rest Services from Log4j 2");
            category.error("Hello Rest Services from Log4j 2");
        }

}
```

But my loggers are not behaving as expected 'AppService.log' is not getting populated. The online examples I saw it uses Loggers instead of Category in java classes. But its very old application with lots of java files which uses "Category" for logging. Is there a way where I don't have to change java classes and modify my log4j2.xml file to accommodate package wise logging. Thanks a lot for your inputs in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make code changes:
This class has been deprecated and replaced by the Logger subclass. It will be kept around to preserve backward compatibility until mid 2003.
Source: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html

Log4j2 bridge doesn't seem to support this:
Applications can migrate by just using the bridge without further code changes, if they meet the following requirements:
They must not access methods and classes internal to the Log4j 1.x implementation such as Appenders, LoggerRepository or Category's callAppenders
Source: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

Comment: The code in the question meets the criteria to use `log4j-1.2-api`. And the `Category` class was never removed.

Comment: Thanks both for your inputs. Helped me to fine tune my log xml now able to generate the logging properly. Just one more query I have added logger on specific server package and db package to print logs only when the logs are warn level to Console Appender and Console appender is also set on debug level in root level. Have edited my xml above please let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not use Log4j2 (packages `org.apache.logging.log4j.*`) but Log4j (1.x, package `org.apache.log4j.*`).

You need to use the Log4j-to-Log4j2 bridge to forward your logging messages to Log4j2 (cf. [migration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html)): this sums up to replacing the [`log4j:log4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j) with [`org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api).

There are also a couple of typos in your configuration:

- the name of the rolling file appender ("Applog") does not match its appender reference ("EDMLog"),
- the `fileName` of the rolling file appender probably points to a non-existent directory `/logs` which your Tomcat server can not create. Try `${sys:catalina.base}/logs/AppService.log` instead.

Instead of adding a `ThresholdFilter` to an appender, you can add a `level` setting to the appender reference:

```xml
<Logger name="com.java.app.restservices.migration"  additivity="false">         
    <AppenderRef ref="Applog" level="INFO"/>
</Logger>
```

Comment: @Karwasz, my bad submitted the confusing code.